# API python module and pytest: real tests need private data to login, how to handle (no mocking)

Tags: pytest, tox

I'm converting some code I've used a few time into my first python package. So I'm thinking about getting the tests to work.

It's for an API and accessing the API requires private information (a key).
Anyone using this module would have their own key. The service provider makes access to a sandbox instance easy (but still authenticated with your private details). So it's practical for any user to run the tests on real endpoints with their own credentials, since they must have credentials to use the module in the first place.

(I want my test cases to actually hit the API, so mocking is not the solution I am looking for. )

Best solution I have is to require the private data to be an environment variable. Is this the best approach?
What are the implications for CI tools like tox? Can they be fed private environment vars in a public repo, that is, my credentials are not part of the repo, not part of a github fork.

Comment: Travis supports encryption of environment variables; I actually use this feature when uploading new releases to PyPI: the password is stored encrypted in `.travis-ci.yml`. However, testing against a remote server will make your tests unstable and your test account will probably be banned in no time once multiple users start to run the tests in their forks.

Comment: What I want is for *my* testing to use my test credentials but with no one else accessing those credentials if they fork; however, I want to easily enable them to test using their own credentials. That's what I mean by feeding private environment variables ... secret to me, despite it being a public repository.

Comment: Thanks for your tip about travis and environment variables. It seems a repository can have private environment variables (not in the .yml but as "repository settings"). If you put that in an answer I will accept it.